# ReactJS call function async and wait for the response before continuing (Login Google Workspace then check user in Backend)

Tags: reactjs

I am building a ReactJS application that uses Google Workspace and a Python backend for logging in users.

The flow is as following

- `useEffect()` loads a Google sign in button
- On frontend the users click "Sign in with Google"
- The frontend calls the function handleCallbackResponse() which prints the Google token.
- The `handleCallbackResponse()` should send the Google token to the Python backend. The function needs to wait until a response from backend is given. The call to backend happens in `loginBackend`.
- My problem is that the variable `const backendToken` is set to "[object Promise]". However I need it to be set to the response from the backend.

I created a drawing of the flow:

[image]

**index.html**

I added Google client script

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes ,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Login from './pages/Login/Login';
import useToken from './useToken';


import Layout from "./pages/Layout";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import NoPage from "./pages/NoPage";


function App() {

  const { token, setToken } = useToken();

  if(!token) {
    return <Login setToken={setToken} />
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Application</h1>
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
                  <Route index element={<Home />} />
                  <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
                  <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
              </Route>
          </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**useToken.js**

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function useToken() {
  const getToken = () => {
    const tokenString = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
    return userToken?.token
  };

  const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());

  const saveToken = userToken => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
    setToken(userToken.token);
    console.log(userToken.token)
  };

  return {
    setToken: saveToken,
    token
  }
}
```

**pages/Login/Login.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './Login.css';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode"

const google = window.google;
export default function Login({ setToken }) {

  // Handle response from Google login
  function handleCallbackResponse(response){
    console.log("Google token: " + response.credential)
    var userObject = jwt_decode(response.credential)
    var userEmail = userObject.email;
    console.log("userEmail=" + userEmail)
    document.getElementById("sign_in_form_google").hidden = true;

    // Call login on backend async  async e => {loginBackend(response.credential)};
    const backendToken = loginBackend(response.credential)
    console.log("Backend token: " + backendToken)
    setToken(backendToken);

  }

  // Login to backend
  async function loginBackend(credentials){
    console.log("Login.js :: loginBackend():: Logging in with " + credentials)
    var backendToken = fetch('https://localhost:5000/api/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + credentials

        }
      }).then(data => data.json())
    console.log("Login.js :: loginBackend() :: Response is " + backendToken)
    return backendToken
  }

  // Google Login 
  useEffect(() => {
    /* global google */
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: "xxx-yyy.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      callback: handleCallbackResponse
    });

    google.accounts.id.renderButton(
      document.getElementById("sign_in_button_google"),
      { theme: "outline", size: "large" }
    )

    google.accounts.id.prompt();

  }, []);

  return(
    <div className="body_bg">
      <div className="wrapper">
          {/* User login header */}
          <header>
            <div className='header_left'>
              <p>My website</p>
            </div>
            <div className='header_right'>
              <img src="gfx/login/logo_100x49.png" alt="Logo" />
            </div>
          </header>

          {/* User login main */}
          <main>
            <h1>Please Log In</h1>

            {/* Login form */ }
            <div id="sign_in_form_google">
              <p>Use Google to login below.</p>
              <div id="sign_in_button_google"></div>
            </div>
          </main>

          {/* User login footer */}
          <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2022 Me</p>
          </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

Login.propTypes = {
  setToken: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

**pages/Layout.js:**

```
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
};

export default Layout;
```

**pages/Home.js:**

```
import { getValue } from "@testing-library/user-event/dist/utils";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import { UserContext } from "../useToken";

import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode"

export function Home() {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>

    </div>
    );
}
  
export default Home;
```

**paegs/About.js:**

```
import { useContext } from "react";

export function About() {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>About</h1>

      

    </div>
    );
}
  
export default About;
```

**pages/NoPage.js:**

```
const NoPage = () => {
    return <h1>404</h1>;
  };
    
  export default NoPage;
```

Console output:

```
Login.js:11 Google token: eyxxx
Login.js:14 userEmail=xxx@yyyy.com
Login.js:26 Login.js :: loginBackend():: Logging in with eyxxx
Login.js:35 Login.js :: loginBackend() :: Response is [object Promise]
Login.js:19 Backend token: [object Promise]
useToken.js:15 undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `handleCallbackResponse` async and await `loginBackend`:

```js
    async function handleCallbackResponse(response){
        console.log("Google token: " + response.credential)
        var userObject = jwt_decode(response.credential)
        var userEmail = userObject.email;
        console.log("userEmail=" + userEmail)
        document.getElementById("sign_in_form_google").hidden = true;
    
        // Call login on backend async  async e => {loginBackend(response.credential)};
        const backendToken = await loginBackend(response.credential)
        console.log("Backend token: " + backendToken)
        setToken(backendToken);
    }
```